# FadeIn effect and diagonal movement at the same time using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, responsive-design, fadein, effect

I want to create the same effect in the link below...
http://ampolla.com.br/testing/Untitled.html

I want a fadeIn effect and a diagonal movement at the same time using jQuery.

The effect of the link has been created by me using an Mac app called Hype, but it's in HTML5 and the image is called in the Javascript file. The problem is that for responsive projects, I need the image called in the html or css files.

Thaks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this task without jQuery I do like this

Give the transition property and duration for your image in css file:

```
transition: left 1s linear;
transition: top 1s linear;
transition: opacity 1s linear;
```

(Also don't forget to change the 'position' property of the element. By default the position is static and you can't move the element with the static position)

And then fire the events from javascript to change the property

```
var myImage = document.getElementById('myElementId');
myImage.style.left = 400;
myImage.style.top = 400;
myImage.style.opacity = 1;
```

Or as you asked for jQuery its more simple

```
$(#idOfYourElement).animate({
   left:400,
   top:400,
   opacity:1
},1000);   //here 1000 is the duration of animation in milliseconds
```

Your initial opacity should be 0.
[Three cheers for jQuery....{it highly simplifies the task}]